# Writing an analytic function in a symmetric region

Tags: complex-analysis

I am to answer the following question:

> Show that every function $f$ which is analytic in a symmetric region $\Omega$ can be written in the form $f_1 + if_2$ where $f_1, f_2$ are analytic in $\Omega$ and real on the real axis.

I want to use the reflection principle, but I understand applying that when we are trying to extend the region. I'm confused on how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$f_1(z) = \frac{f(z) + \overline{f(\overline{z})}}{2}$$